# Iterate result set like array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, loops, join

How I can in MySQL **fetch any row by index from result set** as it possible with arrays or collections in most *programming languages* ?

```
array[index]
```

Or:

```
collection.getElementByIndex(index)
```

### Update:

I have a result set of dates, me need to check whether the 90 days between each date

Comment: Indexes do not really make sense in a table, so the question is rather *why* you want to do? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @MatsKindahl I add more info. *Check updates*

Comment: Then you can write a query that return all rows that match the criteria. Do you want to have the first or the second row? Do you want the row if it is 90 days *exactly* between the dates, or *less than* 90 days between the dates, or *more than* 90 days between the dates.

Comment: @MatsKindahl Result should give me the **boolean** answer *is 90 days or more between all dates ?*

Comment: See the answer below, it contain two different ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

1. Use a a sub-select.
2. Use the ability for MySQL to iterate over the returned rows.

First alternative looks like:

```
SELECT BIT_AND(IFNULL(DATEDIFF((SELECT dt FROM foo WHERE dt > a.dt ORDER BY dt LIMIT 1), a.dt) >= 90, 1)) AS all_larger
  FROM foo a;
```

**Update:** To handle a table where a date is duplicated, it is necessary to add a second sub-select to see if there are duplicates for the date, as follows:

```
SELECT BIT_AND(larger && ! duplicates) AS all_larger
  FROM (SELECT a.dt
             , IFNULL(DATEDIFF((SELECT dt FROM foo WHERE dt > a.dt ORDER BY dt LIMIT 1), a.dt) >= 90, 1) AS larger
             , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE dt = a.dt) > 1 AS duplicates
          FROM foo a) AS x;
```

Second alternative looks like:

```
SET @prev = NULL;
SELECT BIT_AND(a.larger) AS all_larger
  FROM (SELECT IFNULL(DATEDIFF(dt, @prev) >= 90, 1) AS larger
             , @prev := dt
          FROM foo ORDER BY dt) a;
```

Both give the following result set when run on a table where the difference between the dates are more than 90 days:

```
+------------+
| all_larger |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

The second one is probably faster, but I haven't measured on larger sets.

Comment: It's work fine. But when I have two same dates `2014-05-11, 2014-05-11` the result is `1` should be `0`

Comment: Which one? The last one return 0 when I try it with two identical dates in the table.

Comment: This is my full **[query](https://gist.github.com/dozortsev/462065358f6a756c3456)** and it return `12`(UserId) should `NULL` when I have duplicate dates

Comment: Updated the answer to include the case where you have duplicate entries. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Still have problem. When I have only two dates `2014-05-11, 2014-05-11`  result should be `0` when I have follow set `2014-02-10 ` **`2014-05-11, 2014-05-11`** `2014-10-23` the result shoul be `1`. As alternative need use `DISTINCT` set of dates.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you want two identical dates to count as two separate entries (hence not 90 days or more between) the result will be false if you use the updated query. If you do not want two identical dates to count as distinct dates, you can use the first query (which ignore identical dates). Why do you want to make an exception for the first case? Using distinct will remove duplicates, so that does not help. Can you show some examples and what result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Intrinsically you cannot.  A relational database doesn't preserve record order (or at least you can't rely on it, even if it temporarily stores record order).  In this way it acts more like a hashmap or List than an array.

However if you want, you can add a field in the table - let's call it RowNum - that stores a row number, and you can query on that.

```
select * from Table where RowNum = %index%;
```